# Meaning of a formula

Tags: linear-algebra

$N(n+1)=N(n)+1$

Does this mean "$N$ at point $(n+1)$ is equal to $N+1$? This seems redundant. The author of the text that using this formula "you will eventually get to every other point by going either to the future or going to the past." I get that. But then I'm confused by this formula: $N(n+1) = N(n) + 2$. The author states that if you start with an odd number, you never get to an even number and vice versa. Seem obvious if one plugs in odd or even numbers for $N$. I think I'm missing the point.

Comment: Difference between two odd numbers is always even and difference between an odd and even number is always odd. If you start with odd, with increment of $2$, you're simply jumping to the next odd number. Hence, you can never reach an even number. This is the intuitive explanation. An algebraic one can be given by taking $2k$ as an even value and $2m+1$ as an odd value and then using the given functional recurrence.

Answer (score 1):

It means the $(n+1)^{th}$ term is $1$ more than the $n^{th}$ term.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the next step in the series will be the previous one, add 1

So

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

would work,

but so would

2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9